# Vue.js filter values from two store

Tags: vue.js

I need help with getters in Vue.js, I'm trying to get list of data that is connected with id in two different stores.
Here is structure:

```
pageUser {
  pageId,
  userId,
  type,
  weight
}

user {
  id,
  name,
  age,
  city  
}
```

This is code I have for now:

```
state: () => {
  return {
    images: [
      {id: '1', name:'John', age: 23, city: 'Boston'},
      {id: '2', name:'Jack', age: 34, city: 'Miami'}
    ]
  }
},

getters: {
list: (state, pageId) => (key) => {
  return map(state[key], function (s) {
    return {
      id: s.id,
      name: s.name,
      age: s.age,
      city: s.city
    }
  })
}
```

This return me list of all users, but I need to make some filtering, when I go to page for example with id '2586' I need to get list of user that belong that page and they should be sorted by weight.
I'm pretty new in Vue.js and I really don't know how to make this.

Answer (score 0):

```
getters: {
 getUser: state => id => {
  return user

  // Create a new array of objects merging both the states
  .map(u => {
   return {
    ...pageUser.find(pu => pu.userId === u.id),
    u
   }
  })

  // Filter by id provided to the getter
  .filter(u => u.id === id)

  // Sort on basis of weight
  .sort((a,b) => {
    if (a.weight < b.weight) {
      return -1
    }
    else if (a.weight > b.weight)) {
      return 1
    }
    return 0
  })
 }
}
```

Call the getter in your component:

```
this.$store.getters.getUser('2586')
```